# JOIN Three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have this database "stats19" with all data from UK accidents from 2005 to 2013

Now I have to create a DataWarehouse (star type).

This are the tables i'm trying to join in one table, omitting some other variables that are not important

stats19.casualty (2,020,000 rows)

```
AccidentIndex   varchar(13)
VehicleReference    int(11)
CasualtyReference_id    int(11)
CasualtyClass   int(11)
CasualtySeverity    varchar(7)
CasualtySex varchar(28)
CasualtyAgeBand varchar(7)
...
```

stats19.typeperson (2,020,000 rows)

```
CasualtyType_id int(11)
fk_AccidentIndex    varchar(13)
fk_VehicleReference int(11)
fk_CasualtyReference_id int(11)
...
```

stats19.accident (1,494,275 rows)

```
AccidentIndex   varchar(13)
AccidentDate    date
AccidentTime    time
...
```

Final table must have this variables

dw.casualtytemporary (should have 202.000 rows)

```
AccidentIndex VARCHAR(255),
VehicleReference INT,
CasualtyReference INT,
CasualtyClass INT,
CasualtyType INT,
AccidentDate DATE,
AccidentTime TIME,
CasualtySex VARCHAR(255),
CasualtyAgeBand VARCHAR(255)
```

I have been trying to execute this to insert

```
INSERT INTO CasualtyTemp
    (SELECT c.AccidentIndex,c.VehicleReference,c.CasualtyReference_id,
    c.CasualtyClass,t.CasualtyType_id,a.AccidentDate,a.AccidentTime,
    c.CasualtySex, c.CasualtyAgeBand
    FROM (stats19.Casualty as c 
        INNER JOIN stats19.typeperson as t 
            ON c.CasualtyReference_id = t.cf_CasualtyReference_id
        INNER JOIN stats19.accident as a
            ON a.AccidentIndex = c.AccidentIndex))
);
```

The problem comes when MYSQL CommandLine or Workbench both fail inserting by getting an error (disconnection) or taking too much time to do the insert.

Final table dw.casualtytemporary should have 2,020,000 rows as this is what the original table had.

Comment: So, your question is how to make the query faster? Or how to increase the timeout on the client so it doesn't disconnect before this finishes?

Comment: did you check you `select` query ? if you are sure about data, use `LIMIT 10000` for example  then. and then continue with `LIMIT 10000,10000` and so on. it is just timeout issue

Comment: My question is Am I doing it wrong? Or, am I doing it right and should try something refered to increase timeout or optimization? The select does work with the limit 1000 or limit 1000,1000 (offset). Problem comes when the join is suposed to generate 2,020,000 rows and when doing an offset 2,000,000 that inserts up to 3,000,000 rows into the destiny table.

Comment: Another alternative is to use date ranges so you are moving less data at a time.  I assume you are only going to have to move the historical data once.

Comment: historical time is already inserted in a dimension that is shared by three base tables as (concat(date,time),date,time).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing full table join without 'where', so I think the search complexity is `n1*log(n2)*log(n3)` where ni is the row number of each table(if you use index on the inner join field).

I think your SQL statement is right, and mysql optimizer will further optimize the SQL, so I think no need to do on the SQL. But I think you can tune the MYSQL part, I list something that maybe important.

1. Both storage engine should be same, this can ensure that the tables are join in engine level, else they will join on server level which is slow.
2. If you use Innodb, maybe you can tune the important parameters related to Inoodb, like 'Innodb_buffer_pool_size', because enough space will make innodb do hash index in memory.
3. If you use Myisam engine, maybe you can tune the myisam index size to ensure the index can load into memory.
4. Also, since you will produce derived table, so tmp_table_size will be important, if tmp_table_size is small, the myisam table will be used as tmp table. Also note innodb is very slow to write due to the double write log mechanism, and this will be further worse when you are using insert...select, since concurrent insert is disable.
5. Other factors like if there are NULL in your field, if the field repeat heavily and if so, you can use ENUM which is faster than VARCHAR. Also notice CHAR is about 20% faster than VARCHAR, in case disk space is not a concern and string is short maybe can try.

If all of above can't resolve your problem or you don't have a big machine, since you are doing only three table, you can program some code in c/c++, which is the most efficient way.